# update using get the records from html form code not working

Tags: php

[This is the php code thats getting the record from view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tTre.jpg)

[the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBZqI.jpg)

[the update code which z not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocCXA.jpg)

Comment: You should have posted actual code, but the image of the query was clear enough for me to close the question.

Answer (score -1):

First Read This **[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)**

> Notice the WHERE clause in the UPDATE syntax: The WHERE clause
>   specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit
>   the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET field = '$variable',field2 = '$variable2'";
```

In Your code problem is in your update query. check that manualy.